# Is there any c compiler that shows me each step of a recursive function?

Tags: c, recursion

Currently I am writing a quicksort algorithm in c (I'm a beginner) and it's really hard for me to understand the recursion. It is not my first program with a recursive function so I would like to know if there is any compiler for c that shows the steps of a recursive function to get it easier.

Comment: Not a compiler, but a debugger. With a modern IDE, it's user friendly and you can see the execution, step by step until the resolution.

Comment: Remember to specify the environment you’re working in, when asking for a tool recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

Use Visual Studio IDE , There is a free version available.
you can view the call stack using this IDE. 
or Use CodeBlocks IDE

Answer (score 1):

While you can use an IDE to step through the recursion, I find the most instructive thing for students is to use printf at the start of your recursive function. (Actually THE most instructive task is to hand execute a recursive function using paper and pen, but this gets old fast for deep recursion!)

Example:

```
int fibonacci(int n) {
    printf("fibonacci(%d)\n", n);
    if (n == 0 || n == 1)
    return n;
  else
    return (fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2));
}
```

This will produce the following recursion trace. With double recursion, this unfortunately does not make it clear what calls what:

```
fib 4
fibonacci(4)
fibonacci(3)
fibonacci(2)
fibonacci(1)
fibonacci(0)
fibonacci(1)
fibonacci(2)
fibonacci(1)
fibonacci(0)
fibonacci(4)=3
```

If you don't mind adding a recursion count to your recursive function, you can get a nicely indented output using the follow code (as an example):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void traceResursion(const char *funcName, int n, int recursionLevel)
{ 
 int i;
 if (recursionLevel > 0) {
    for(i=0; i<recursionLevel; i++)
       printf("   ");
    printf("-->"); 
 }
 printf("%s(%d)\n", funcName, n);
} 


int fibonacci(int n, int recursionLevel) {
    traceResursion("fibonacci", n, recursionLevel);
    if (n == 0 || n == 1)
    return n;
  else
    return (fibonacci(n-1, recursionLevel+1) + fibonacci(n-2, recursionLevel+1));
}  

int main(int argc, char **argv){
      int n = 2;

      /* Get n from the command line if provided */
      if (argc > 1)
         n = atoi(argv[1]);

      printf("fibonacci(%d)=%d\n", n, fibonacci(n,0));
}
```

This accepts a command line number and computes the fibonacci and display the recursion. For example, if you compiled this into executable fib, then the following command:

```
fib 5
```

Produces the following output that shows the recursion.

```
> fib 5 
fibonacci(5)
   -->fibonacci(4)
      -->fibonacci(3)
         -->fibonacci(2)
            -->fibonacci(1)
            -->fibonacci(0)
         -->fibonacci(1)
      -->fibonacci(2)
         -->fibonacci(1)
         -->fibonacci(0)
   -->fibonacci(3)
      -->fibonacci(2)
         -->fibonacci(1)
         -->fibonacci(0)
      -->fibonacci(1)
fibonacci(5)=5
```

Do something similar for your QuickSort to create a similar recursion trace.

Comment: Thank you very much! I used to write it on paper, but because I had to test the program several times before it worked I wasted much paper.

Answer (score 1):

As an extension to the excellent suggestion by [ScottK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53918777/1475978), I recommend using [Graphviz](https://www.graphviz.org/) to aid in the visualization.  It is available for all operating systems, and is completely free.  It takes human-readable text (Dot language) as input, and provides rather nice graphs as output.

Consider the following Fibonacci example program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static inline int  unique_id(void)
{
    static int  id = 0;
    return ++id;
}

static int  dot_fibonacci_recursive(int n, int parent_id, FILE *out)
{
    const int  id = unique_id();

    if (n < 2) {
        printf("    \"%d\" [ label=< %d. F<sub>%d</sub> = <b>1</b> > ];\n", id, id, n);
        printf("    \"%d\" -> \"%d\";\n", id, parent_id);

        return 1;
    } else {
        int result1, result2;

        result1 = dot_fibonacci_recursive(n - 1, id, out);
        result2 = dot_fibonacci_recursive(n - 2, id, out);

        printf("    \"%d\" [ label=< %d. F<sub>%d</sub> = <b>%d</b> > ];\n", id, id, n, result1 + result2);
        printf("    \"%d\" -> \"%d\";\n", id, parent_id);

        return result1 + result2;
    }
}

int  fibonacci(int n)
{
    const int  id = unique_id();
    int        result;

    printf("digraph {\n");

    result = dot_fibonacci_recursive(n, id, stdout);

    printf("    \"%d\" [ label=< %d. F<sub>%d</sub> = <b>%d</b> > ];\n", id, id, n, result);
    printf("}\n");
    fflush(stdout);

    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int  n, fn;
    char dummy;

    if (argc != 2 || !strcmp(argv[1], "-h") || !strcmp(argv[1], "--help")) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [ -h | --help ]\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "       %s N > graph.dot\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "This program will compute the N'th Fibonacci number\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "using a recursive function, and output the call graph\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "as a dot language directed graph.\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Use e.g. 'dot' from the Graphviz package to generate\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "an image, or display the graph interactively. For example:\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "       dot -Tsvg graph.dot > graph.svg\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (sscanf(argv[1], " %d %c", &n, &dummy) != 1 || n < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Invalid N.\n", argv[1]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    fn = fibonacci(n);

    fprintf(stderr, "%d'th Fibonacci number is %d.\n", n, fn);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

It takes a single parameter on the command line, and outputs the recursive call graph for the simple recursive Fibonacci implementation.

For example, if we compile and run the above *dot-fibonacci.c* in Linux using GCC,

```
gcc -Wall -O2 dot-fibonacci.c -o dot-fibonacci
./dot-fibonacci 4 | dot -Tx11
```

we see the call graph
[image: 4th Fibonacci number call graph]
The number in front identifies the call to the recursive function (`dot_fibonacci()`), with the outermost `fibonacci()` call being first.  Because my `fibonacci()` is just a wrapper function that does no calculation, the root node is always the same as the second node (first actual call to `dot_fibonacci()`).

The Dot language text that generates the above graph is

```
digraph {
    "5" [ label=< 5. F<sub>1</sub> = <b>1</b> > ];
    "5" -> "4";
    "6" [ label=< 6. F<sub>0</sub> = <b>1</b> > ];
    "6" -> "4";
    "4" [ label=< 4. F<sub>2</sub> = <b>2</b> > ];
    "4" -> "3";
    "7" [ label=< 7. F<sub>1</sub> = <b>1</b> > ];
    "7" -> "3";
    "3" [ label=< 3. F<sub>3</sub> = <b>3</b> > ];
    "3" -> "2";
    "9" [ label=< 9. F<sub>1</sub> = <b>1</b> > ];
    "9" -> "8";
    "10" [ label=< 10. F<sub>0</sub> = <b>1</b> > ];
    "10" -> "8";
    "8" [ label=< 8. F<sub>2</sub> = <b>2</b> > ];
    "8" -> "2";
    "2" [ label=< 2. F<sub>4</sub> = <b>5</b> > ];
    "2" -> "1";
    "1" [ label=< 1. F<sub>4</sub> = <b>5</b> > ];
}
```

Note that the order of the indented lines is not important. You can reorder them if you like, for easier understanding.

- The quoted parts are node identifiers.
- `->` creates an arrow from one node to another.
- The `label=< ... >` formats the text inside the label as HTML. You can also use `label="string"` for simple strings, and `shape="record", label="thing | { foo | bar } | baz"` for structured labels. You can direct arrows to such subfields as well.

As you can see, the basics are really simple; `dot` (or one of the other visualizers in the Graphviz package) really does the hard part of choosing how to represent the data.

To implement such dot graph output in your own programs:

1. Make sure all informational output goes to standard error; use

   ```
    fprintf(stderr, "Information ...\n");
   ```

   instead of `printf()`. Only use `printf(...)` or `fprintf(stdout, ...)` when outputting the Dot language stuff.  This lets you redirect the standard output from your program to a file by appending `> filename.dot` to the command line.
2. Start your directional graph with

   ```
    printf("digraph {\n");
   ```

   and end it with

   ```
    printf("}\n");
   ```

   The edges and nodes go in between. Their order does not matter.

   (If you want an non-directional graph, use `graph {`, and `--` for the edges.)
3. A node is defined using `"id" [ ... ];` where `id` is the identifier used to address that node, and `...` is a comma-separated list of attributes.

   Typical attributes you need are `shape="record", label="foo | bar"` for structured labels; `label=< HTML >` or `shape="none", label=< HTML >` for HTML-formatted labels, and `label="foo"` for simple text labels.  If you omit the label (or the entire node specification), the `id` is used for the label instead.

   To visualize e.g. trees or lists or anything using pointers, use

   ```
    printf(" \"%p\" [ ... ];\n", (void *)ptr);
   ```

   which uses the actual pointer value as the source for the node ID.
4. Directed edges have form

   ```
   "source-id" -> "target-id";
   ```

   or

   ```
   "source-id" -> "target-id" [ color="#rrggbb" ];
   ```

   In addition to color, you can label the arrows using `taillabel`, `headlabel`, and so on.

That's about all you need, although you can find additional [examples](https://www.graphviz.org/gallery/) and [documentation](https://www.graphviz.org/documentation/) all over the web.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try.